# Django REST Framework many to many create and update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
  image = models.ImageField(height_field="height_field", width_field="width_field")
  height_field = models.IntegerField(default=255)
  width_field = models.IntegerField(default=255)
  price = models.FloatField()
  edition = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  no_of_page = models.IntegerField()
  country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='AuthorBook')
  ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='books')

class AuthorBook(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  biography = models.TextField(max_length=500)
  image = models.ImageField(height_field="height_field", width_field="width_field")
  height_field = models.IntegerField(default=255)
  width_field = models.IntegerField(default=255)
```

serializers.py

```
class AuthorListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  url = author_detail_url
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = [
      'url',
      'id',
      'name',
    ]

class BookCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  authors = AuthorListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

  def create(self, validated_data):
    #code

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    #code

  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = [
      'name',
      'description',
      'price',
      'edition',
      'no_of_page',
      'country',
      'publication',
      'authors',
    ]
```

views.py

```
class BookCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
  queryset = Book.objects.all()
  serializer_class = BookCreateUpdateSerializer
```

I am working for implementing Django REST Framework. I have two models `Book` and `Author`. But django create api view don't show authors field drop down. I checked many solution DRF for many to many field. Please help me to show authors field and write `create()` and `update` function. If you see DRF api page, it will be clear.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [`read_only=True`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only). Try to remove this argument for bookserializer's authors field:

```
class BookCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    authors = AuthorListSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: it shows `Authors
Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.`

Comment: @SadmanSobhan Looks like it's opened issue github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2148 for this. You can use postman instead of browsable api